# 2 Domains at 1 Hosting

Tags: dns, hosting

I have a simple question - can I run two domains at the same hosting?

I have: mywebsite.ru and mywebsite.kz, these are two simple html pages with different information. At my publick_html I have a folder "mywebsite.kz", when I upload files in there .kz works well, but I cannot find folder called mywebsite.ru and I cannot add it as an extra domain, coz it says that this one already exists but shows a different name (something like "mywebsite.hosting.user.ru")...

Thanks in advance and all the best wishes!

Answer (score 0):

Hosting multiple domains on same server is possible using virtual host. Check with your provider if virtual host is enabled for your hosting service, If you have ssh access to your server than you can do it on your own.